# Using COM objects in nodejs native module

Tags: node.js, winapi, com

I have a question about using COM objects in native nodejs module. I want to hook up for events sent by COM server, but none is received. I tried everything but none seems to work. Her's the problem:

I want to use QR code scanner that exposes functionality by COM component. Initializing nodejs native module and COM objects is flawless, I can even communicate with scanner just fine. Problem starts, when scanner tries to send async event of QR code read. I tried to hook up for events by `IConnectionPointContainer` like this:

```cpp
scanner_event_sink = new EventSink();
scanner_event_sink_unknown = scanner_event_sink->GetIDispatch(FALSE);

hr = scanner_interface->QueryInterface(IID_IConnectionPointContainer, (void **)&m_connContainer);
hr = m_connContainer->FindConnectionPoint(DIID__ICoreScannerEvents, &m_connPoint);
hr = m_connPoint->Advise(scanner_event_sink_unknown, &cookie);
```

All is ok, but I receive no events.
I tried spawning separate thread with winapi message loop, initializing COM in multithread configuration etc. and none of it works. Funny enough - standalone console app with the same code works.

I've run out of options, and started to think that maybe something with compilation options is wrong ? `Advise` method returns no error, other COM calls to scanner interface works, no COM errors, all libs are loaded OK, I'm not blocking nodejs thread etc...

Does somebody used COM objects in native nodejs module ? How to get those events ?

## EDIT:

Example function that executes COM in separate thread [nodejs COM sample](https://gist.github.com/bemon/7fcd10b00be2062301d93512c2fe4623)

I tried to run COM in STA thread with message loop, no events by EventSink is received. As I said before - running from console works just fine.

Comment: An STA thread needs to dispatch messages. From the code provided it's neither apparent whether the calling thread initializes an STA nor whether there is a message loop. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: **Every** thread that's using COM needs to be initialized, either into an STA or the MTA. Your code doesn't. See [Why does CoCreateInstance work even though my thread never called CoInitialize? The curse of the implicit MTA](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130419-00/?p=4613). Since that is apparently new to you, it's anyone's guess why your implementation running in an STA doesn't receive events. Again, please show a [mcve], **in the question itself**.

Comment: Same problem here. Was it solved? 
For me  the same code from Zebra ZDK example works in console application. And does not work when wrapped in NodeJS module.
By "Works" I mean I get events in console application and nothing happend when it is wrapped in NodeJS.

Comment: There is CoInitialize call and there is event pump. Something is missing.  No matter if I call the sample code from Nodej main thread (just to test), std::thread or AfxBeginThread.

Comment: I am talking about this code
https://github.com/zebra-technologies/Scanner-SDK-for-Windows-Code-Snippets/blob/master/CPP/RegisterUnregisterForEvents/register_unregister_for_events.cpp